# How can I acess a array from node.js in javacsript with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

So I am making a app where it needs to pass an array from the server into the client. I have tried to do

```
// Server
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    data: ["Hello"]
  })
})

// EJS
<script>
  const data = '<%- JSON.stringify(locals.data) || [] %>'
</script>
```

But then its not an array in the ejs so I tried

```
// Server
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    data: ["Hello"]
  })
})

// EJS
<script>
  const data = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(locals.data) || [] %>')
</script>
```

That worked until I passed an array with a `'` in it, is there anyway that I can pass the array into javascript with having problems with having certain charters?

This is working with a discord  bot to get the servers and display them on a page. So I want to make sure it can show all the charaters.

And if I change the `'` to `"` or ` it could still cause issues with some inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the best way is to just use `JSON.parse(<%- JSON.stringify(locals.data) || [] %>)` as ejs will automatically render that even though it might just look a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, but i had to remove the `const data = JSON.parse(<%- JSON.stringify(locals.data) || [] %>) ` and just have it as `const data = <%- JSON.stringify(locals.data) || [] %>`

Comment: Oh yea, it just slipped out of my mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats to @hacKaTun3s for this answer:

```
const data = <%- JSON.stringify(locals.data) || [] %>
```

But this causes sytax errors and can be annoying, so i am using this:

EJS:

```
<p hidden id=scrpt_get_locals><%= JSON.stringify(locals) %></p>
```

It will be hidden and in the script we will access its contents.

JAVASCRIPT: (DEFER)

```
const locals = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('scrpt_get_locals').innerText) // Get element text that has locals, then parse it
document.getElementById('scrpt_get_locals').innerText = '' // Remove the text (So we don't have a random element with the locals
document.getElementById('scrpt_get_locals').id = '' // Remove id (Optional)
```

Edit:

Top access the variable data you would:

```
console.log(locals.data)
```